Performance issues (and suitability) of react-beautiful-dnd with many (200+ droppables)?
I am making React Material-UI react-beautiful-dnd component which display number of TV breaks (each break is in a separate panel/dnd droppable) and each TV break displays the list of ads inside the break. My most minimal code is this:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { DragDropContext, Droppable, Draggable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';
import { Paper, List, ListItem, ListItemText, Box, Typography } from '@mui/material';

// Initial ads data
const initialAds = [
  { itemNo: 1, breakNum: 1 },
  { itemNo: 2, breakNum: 1 },
  { itemNo: 3, breakNum: 2 },
  { itemNo: 4, breakNum: 2 },
  { itemNo: 5, breakNum: 3 },
  { itemNo: 6, breakNum: 3 },
  { itemNo: 7, breakNum: 4 },
  { itemNo: 8, breakNum: 4 },
  { itemNo: 9, breakNum: 5 },
  { itemNo: 10, breakNum: 5 }
];

const MinimalDragDrop = () => {
  const [ads, setAds] = useState(initialAds);

  const onDragEnd = (result) => {
    const { source, destination } = result;

    // Dropped outside the list
    if (!destination) {
      return;
    }

    // Dropped in the same place
    if (
      source.droppableId === destination.droppableId &&
      source.index === destination.index
    ) {
      return;
    }

    // Find the ad being moved
    const draggedAd = ads.find(ad => ad.itemNo === parseInt(result.draggableId));

    // Update the breakNum of the dragged ad
    const updatedAds = ads.map(ad =>
      ad.itemNo === draggedAd.itemNo
        ? { ...ad, breakNum: parseInt(destination.droppableId.split('_')[1]) }
        : ad
    );

    setAds(updatedAds);
  };

  const renderPanel = (breakNum) => {
    return (
      <Box key={breakNum} display="flex" flexDirection="column" alignItems="flex-start" padding="0.5rem" margin="0.5rem" border="1px solid lightgray" width="200px">
        <Typography variant="body1" style={{ fontSize: '0.8rem', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
          Break {breakNum}
        </Typography>
        <Droppable droppableId={`panel_${breakNum}`}>
          {(provided) => (
            <List {...provided.droppableProps} ref={provided.innerRef} style={{ maxHeight: 150, overflow: 'auto', padding: '0.5rem' }}>
              {ads
                .filter(ad => ad.breakNum === breakNum)
                .map((ad, index) => (
                  <Draggable key={ad.itemNo} draggableId={ad.itemNo.toString()} index={index}>
                    {(provided) => (
                      <ListItem
                        ref={provided.innerRef}
                        {...provided.draggableProps}
                        {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                        style={{ ...provided.draggableProps.style, fontSize: '0.6rem', padding: '0.2rem', margin: '0px' }}
                      >
                        <ListItemText primary={`Ad ${ad.itemNo}`} primaryTypographyProps={{ style: { fontSize: '0.7rem' } }} />
                      </ListItem>
                    )}
                  </Draggable>
                ))}
              {provided.placeholder}
            </List>
          )}
        </Droppable>
      </Box>
    );
  };

  return (
    <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
      <Paper style={{ padding: '1rem', display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>
        {renderPanel(1)}
        {renderPanel(2)}
        {renderPanel(3)}
        {renderPanel(4)}
        {renderPanel(5)}
      </Paper>
    </DragDropContext>
  );
};

export default MinimalDragDrop;

It is quite conscise: Droppable panel has droppableId, the draggable div has draggableId and onDragEnd receives as arguments source and destination Droppable with their id's and the draggableId. If I am assigning semantical droppablId and draggableId, then I can immediatly do the data update inside onDragEnd which I am doing in this example.
This is minimal example. But my full code contains Redux store/RTK Toolkit/slice and approximately 200+ breaks (hence Droppable panels). And I am doing the the observation of render with Firefox Web Developer Tools and Compontes/Performance tools from React Developer Tools and I can observer that just the touching and dragging the item makes re-render almost all of breaks although dragging visually encouters just two breaks/panels/Droppables - soure and destination and I am choosing the neighbour panels for my initial tests.
So - is react-beautiful-dnd suitable for 200+ Droppable panels in one DragDropContext and are there mechanisms, prevention of rerender of remaining Droppable panels if I am just dragging from one to another neighbouring panels?
Practically touching/dragging (getting grabbed) item takes around full second in the production implementationa and that is lot of time - DD is supposed to be done at the parts of seconds.
I am trying to reason how the react-beautiful-dnd may handle all this and I have no idea about basic. Maybe HTML/DOM has in-built DD features and the item (e.g. DOM element div, etc.) can be visually captured and dragged already at the HTML/DOM level and react-beautiful-dnd should do just accounting. But may be possible as well that HTML/DOM has no DD support and that is why react-beautiful-dnd may be responsibl for all the visualization of the moving HTML/DOM element? And - in this latter case - the many, many React re-renders may be involved.
